# How to load a class based on exact sub-classes?

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have `Section` class that has list of `ContentItem`s. `ContentItem` has a number of subclasses like `TextContentItem`, `ImageContentItem`, etc. All of them are mapped to database (using class and subclass Maps).

I need to have an ability to retrieve `Section` instance with the populated *exact subclass instances* of `ContentItem`.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `IEnumerable<T>` extension method [`OfType<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb360913%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to filter the collection:

```
var filter = section.ContentItems.OfType<TextContentItem>();
```

If your collection is very large and you want to avoid loading all of the content items, then I would populate a data transfer object (DTO) comprised of the Section class and a collection of the desired content items. I would not advise partially loading the collection in the domain model.